# Can't see samba shares from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

I have shared /media/user and added to smb.conf as read only on Ubuntu 20:04. I can access from my Android phone with Cx File Explorer app, but not from my Ubuntu machines (20:04 and 22:04) The computer are visible, with capital letters in Nautilus and Other locations, but Ubuntu says, fail to retrieve share list from server:In valid argument.

What can I do?

/Cheers

/Edit. I can mount if I knew the share name of the shared folder, but how do I browse smb-shares in my local network in nautilus?

Comment: should the shares not be added to you fstab file on each ubuntu PC?

Comment: On another computer have I make same typ of share, really share all USB-disks that are mount on that system. But I did it 2012 and upgraded. There are nothing I have to do on the client  to get access that share from another Ubuntu machines.